# Mule JMS connector with Websphere default messages provider

Tags: jms, websphere, mule, sibus

We are trying to connect from our mule service to queue. This queue is on Websphere application server and we are using Websphere default messages provider.

How can we set our connector configuration to match this queue ?? 
We are using default JMS connector.. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the section of the IBM Knowledge Center explaining [JNDI Connections to SiBus](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLQQ_8.5.1/com.ibm.rational.rit.was.doc/topics/t_config_sibus_jndi_transports.html).

[image]

Comment: We are not using WebsphereMQ....
We are using Websphere default messaging provider SIbus.
What is the connector configuration for Websphere default messaging provider ?

Comment: You should mention SiBus in your question if you want relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EE, then I recommend using WMQ connector. Documentation available in: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation...

If you have to use JMS, you need to create a spring bean for WebSphere connection factory and use it in your JMS connector connectionFactory-ref attribute.

```
<spring:bean name="MQConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
<spring:property name="hostName" value="localhost"/>
<spring:property name="port" value="1414"/>
<spring:property name="queueManager" value="localmanager"/>
<spring:property name="transportType" value="1"/>
</spring:bean>
```

Don't forget to copy com.ibm.mqjms.jar into your Mule's classpath.

You need to use the com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnectionFactory class instead if you are using XA transactions.